# Swift error: Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add edit some code from Apple's QuestionBot. I came up with this:

```
func responseToQuestion(question: String) -> String {

    if question.hasPrefix("hello") {
        return "Hello"
    } else if question.hasPrefix("where") {
        return "There"
    } else if question.hasPrefix("what"){
        return "I don't know"
    }

}
```

But there's an error: Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'. What should I do, thanks?

Comment: Think about it: what should the function return  if the question has none of the three prefixes?

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

should the function `return` something , because you did not set `return` if do  not match any one `question.hasPrefix()`

```
 func responseToQuestion(question: String) -> String {

            if question.hasPrefix("hello") {
                return "Hello"
            } else if question.hasPrefix("where") {
                return "There"
            } else if question.hasPrefix("what"){
                return "I don't know"
            }
          return "something"
        }
```